# Autolayout - aligning views in table cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am currently porting an iOS application to autolayout and I found a problem I am unable to solve. The problem is a `UITableView`.

The table is pretty simple:

1. Every cell contains two labels, with a horizontal spacing between them.
2. I want the first label to be automatically resized according to content
3. I want the labels in all the cells to have the same width

Points 1. and 2. are simple but I don't know how to create a constraint that will force the views in different cells to have the same sizes.

Is there any autolayout solution for it or do I have to set the frames manually?

Comment: How are 1 and 3 compatible? Do you want all the labels to be the width of the longest text in any cell? Do you also mean that you want the left and right labels the same size too?

Comment: @rdelmar Exactly. I want all the left labels to have the width of the longest text. My only idea is to have a hidden view outside the table and add width constraints (in code) for this view and the left label in every cell.

Comment: Are you sure you want 3? Have you considered edge-cases, such as if you need an accessory view or a delete button on one row?

Comment: @Maarten These cases don't interest me (even scrolling doesn't interest me). Anyway, accessory views or delete buttons shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this by creating a custom cell class with the two labels. Give the left label a width constraint (as well as constraints to the left edge of the cell and centerY) and give the right label a horizontal spacing constraint to the left label. Make IBOutlets to the two labels, and also one to the left label's width constraint (I call it widthCon in my example). In my example I gave both labels a background color so I could see the widths. I calculate the width of the longest string in viewDidLoad, and then use that number to adjust the constant of the width constraint in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
@interface TableController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *theData;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat maxWidth;
@end

@implementation TableController 


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theData = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three Hundred Forty",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine"];
    self.maxWidth = 0;
    for (NSString *s in self.theData) {
        CGSize stringSize = [s sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17]];
        if (stringSize.width > self.maxWidth) self.maxWidth = stringSize.width;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.theData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.widthCon.constant = self.maxWidth;
    cell.leftLabel.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```